# TextView overlapping ImageView in RelativeLayout

Tags: android, listview, textview, imageview, overlap

I've a **listitem.xml** inflated in a getView, for video listing.
When **txtTitle** is long, it overlaps the **arrowImage** on its right, covering it.

Any suggestions to avoid this ? How can the title's text returned on a new line ?

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@drawable/list_selector"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:padding="5dip" >


<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imgIcon"
    android:background="@drawable/image_bg"
    android:layout_width="109dp"
    android:layout_height="68dp"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:padding="3dip"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtTitle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#b0b0b0"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imgIcon"
        android:typeface="sans"
        android:textSize="12dip"
        android:layout_marginLeft="6dip"
        android:layout_marginRight="6dip"
        android:paddingRight="10dip"
        android:textStyle="bold" />


    <ImageView    
    android:id="@+id/arrowImage"
    android:src="@drawable/arrow"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:padding="3dip"
    android:paddingLeft="10dip"
    android:paddingRight="10dip" />

   </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Why don't you use a **compound drawable**? The image will be inside the TextView, so it won't be covered by the text, because it would have its own reserved space inside the TextView.

Comment: try  android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/arrowImage"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imgIcon" in your TEXTVIEW

Comment: should i post as answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this code

Add code in your TextView

```
android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/arrowImage" 
android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imgIcon"
```

**Final code**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:background="@drawable/list_selector"
  android:orientation="horizontal"
  android:padding="5dip" >

          <ImageView
             android:id="@+id/imgIcon"
             android:background="@drawable/image_bg"
             android:layout_width="109dp"
             android:layout_height="68dp"
             android:scaleType="fitXY"
             android:padding="3dip"/>

         <TextView
             android:id="@+id/txtTitle"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:textColor="#b0b0b0"
             android:layout_centerVertical="true"
             android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imgIcon"
             android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/arrowImage"
             android:typeface="sans"
             android:textSize="12dip"
             android:layout_marginLeft="6dip"
             android:layout_marginRight="6dip"
             android:paddingRight="10dip"
             android:textStyle="bold" />

         <ImageView    
             android:id="@+id/arrowImage"
             android:src="@drawable/arrow"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
             android:layout_centerVertical="true"
             android:padding="3dip"
             android:paddingLeft="10dip"
             android:paddingRight="10dip" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a **compound drawable**.
The image will be inside the TextView, so it won't be covered by the text, because it would have its own reserved space inside the TextView.

Mind that **less Views (and/or layouts) = better performances** (this is a **dogma**).

Remove the ImageView and set in your TextView:

```
android:drawableTop|Left|Right|Bottom="@drawable/your_image"
```

In your case,

```
android:drawableLeft="@drawable/your_image"
```

and

```
android:drawableRight="@drawable/arrow_image"
```

---

To set your compound drawable(s) programmatically (once you have a reference to the TextView), just use the `setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds()` method to assign one or more compound images, as described here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(int, int, int, int)

---

The order is: **left**, top, **right**, bottom

Comment: This did the trick (not overlapping). By the way, I need to have arrowImage fixed to the right side. With this solution the arrow is not in fixed position and it changes with the TextView length

Comment: Just do the same with the arrow image! `android:drawableRight="@drawable/arrow_image"` - I updated my answer

Comment: This is the most optimized way to do that.

Comment: The only thing is I should assign dynamic images (imgIcon is the videos thumbles) from the Java code, and setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(int,int,int,int) needs image from R.drawable.

Comment: So what? An image from R.drawable **IS** an int... ;) Meaning that you get the id from R.drawable. So, you can use `setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(R.drawable.image1, R.drawable.image2, null, null)`, for example.

Comment: I actually get the image in this way: holder.thumbImage = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imgIcon);
holder.thumbImage.setImageBitmap(curThumb);

Comment: curThumb is a Bitmap: Bitmap curThumb = MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.getThumbnail(crThumb, ids, MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.MICRO_KIND,     options); I've already tried and that method doesn't accept a Bitmap

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this code?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/relativeLayout1"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgIcon"
            android:background="@drawable/image_bg"
            android:layout_width="109dp"
            android:layout_height="68dp"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:padding="3dip"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtTitle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:textColor="#b0b0b0"
            android:typeface="sans"
            android:textSize="12dip"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/arrowImage"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:src="@drawable/arrow" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```